# How can I bind data with optional dynamic propery keys

Tags: angular

I got an error for this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="editor.testTexts?[editor.currentNsp]?[editor.currentLang]?[key] | safeHtml"></div>
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I suggest you just to use function that will return desired string

Comment: Its not clear what check you are performing and what you want to display.  Explain your question in detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the HTML property using **innerHTML** you need to do like this :

**In your component:** you need to get the HTML properties in the **string**

```
export class TestComponent {
  htmlProps: string = '<h1>Text...</h1>';
}
```

**In your HTML:** access the property  in HTML div element.

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlStr"></div>
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error details and your component properties values?